# Function is not running and creating the text file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, streamwriter

I created the function **pro**:

- it contains the process array
- it calls another write function to make the file and write into it.

the write function **writeproc**:

- it checks if the file at specified path is present or not.
- if not it generates the file else it appends the text into the file.

when i run the code it is not doing anything.... :(
This is the main method for the console app that i have made in c#.

```
[STAThread]
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        pro();
    }
```

pro function:

```
static void pro()
    {

        Process[] localAll = Process.GetProcesses();
        String path_pro = "C://KEYLOGS//processes.txt";
        foreach(Process proc in localAll)
        {
            writeproc(path_pro, proc);
        }
    }
```

writeproc function:

```
static void writeproc(String p, Process the_process)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(p))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(p))
            {
                //empty file generated.
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(p))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Process: "+the_process);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you run it as administrator? Files so close to the root `C:` are likely to be protected

Comment: well other functions are able to write files to the c: directory but only this function is not doing anything

Comment: Which other functions? Can you find any difference between those which work and this one?

Comment: yes those functions contain both arguement as String but this one contains one String path and the other as process.

Comment: Did you check if `localAll` was empty or not?

Comment: if local all was empty then it should still write Process: ""{empty}

Comment: nope, if it was empty, `writeproc` would just never be called because the `foreach` in `pro` would never be entered, thus resulting in nothing being done

Answer (score 0):

This may be the cause of two different things.

1: The folder does not exist on your C drive so the file can't be created. (It will throw a `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException`)
Add `Directory.CreateDirectory(p);` to the start of your writeproc method.

2: You don't have enough rights to write to your C drive. (It will throw a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`)

I suggest adding a breakpoint in your writeproc method to see what exception is being thrown.

Comment: or `localAll` in his `pro` function is empty

Comment: @Rafalon, That's right, it is theoretically possible. However I don't know about a situation when `Process.GetProcesses()` results in an empty array.

Comment: it did work thanks. but still i don't get it . i already had the directory created  then why do i require to create it again?

Comment: Well, the method creates the directory if it doesn't exist. If it exists it will just return the DirectoryInfo of the existing directory. So it looks like the directory didn't exist after all.